# What is a good practive to save hyperparamters for restoring and retraining

Tags: tensorflow, hyperparameters

I just encounter an issue that I have a good model but forgot what hyperparamters I used. I just have the meta, index and data files. I searched if the hyperparamters are saved in those files. But it seems not the case. So what is the best way to save the hyperparamters together with the checkpoint files such that I can retrain at any times with the same parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The simplest solution** would be to pass them as a shorthand notation to the filename, e.g. naming the files something like:

```
Inceptionv4_bs64_lr0.001_Adam
```

If that would make the filename too long, or if you already have a naming convention that you want to keep, just save a text file that has the same name as the other files with a different extension e.g. `.hyperparams`, that contains the information for the hyperparameters.

2. **To save directly into the checkpoint or model files**, you could define a `tf.constant`:

```
learning_rate = tf.constant(0.001)
```

These would be saved in the graph definition and could therefore be recovered if you reload the model or checkpoint files.

3. **If you want something more complex**, tensorflow 2.0 has upgraded the HParams Class into a full Fledged API. This is a bit code heavy, but there is a tutorial notebook provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams). Functionality includes testing over hyperparameter ranges, writing hyperparameters to file and tensorboard visualizations.
4. **Alternatively**, there are also these external platforms that provide similiar functionality to `3.`, are more mature and also work with tensorflow:

- [MLflow](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html)
- [Comet.ml](https://www.comet.ml/)

Comment: Is there something which saves this in meta or checkpoint file?

Comment: See `2.` in my answer. This will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the current date as a model name, and automatically generate a csv file like:

date, path_to_model, hyper_param1, hyper_param2, ..., test acc, val acc, train acc, loss

That way I can easily load in any model that I've previously trained on a new dataset, by just using the date. This structure was pretty nice for me to use, and allows filtering and is easy to read